# Background Worker and ODBC Query

Tags: database, vb.net, odbc, backgroundworker

I want to run the fetching of a Database into a background worker but it seems to be crashing without Visual Studio returning me an error in my code.

Here's the code in the DoWork:

```
Private Sub ITSM_Fetch_BW_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ITSM_Fetch_BW.DoWork
    Dim sql As String = "xxxx"

    Dim ConnString As String = "DRIVER={AR System ODBC Driver};ARServer=xxxx;ARServerPort=xxxx;ARPrivateRpcSocket=xxxx;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;ARAuthentication=;ARUseUnderscores=1;SERVER=NotTheServer"
    Dim connection As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(ConnString)
    connection.Open()

    Dim ODBC_Command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, connection)

    Dim ODBC_reader As Odbc.OdbcDataReader

    'Load the Data into the local Memory
    ODBC_reader = ODBC_Command.ExecuteReader

    e.Result = ODBC_reader
    ODBC_reader.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ITSM_Fetch_BW_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles ITSM_Fetch_BW.RunWorkerCompleted
    Data = New DataTable
    Data.Load(e.Result)

    Dim Count_ToDo(5) As String
    Count_ToDo(0) = "Product_Name"
    Count_ToDo(1) = "Status"
    Count_ToDo(2) = "Language"
    Count_ToDo(3) = "Assigned_Group"
    Count_ToDo(4) = "Priority"
    Count_ToDo(5) = "Company"

    For Each Item As String In Count_ToDo
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim ITEM_Count(0, 1) As String

        For Each Ticket As DataRow In Data.Rows

            'PART FOR THE CI
            If IsDBNull(Ticket.Item(Item)) = False Then

                Dim IsInIndex As Integer = -1
                If i = 0 Then
                    ITEM_Count(0, 0) = Ticket.Item(Item)
                    ITEM_Count(0, 1) = 1
                Else


                    For x As Integer = 0 To ITEM_Count.GetLength(0) - 1
                        If ITEM_Count(x, 0) = Ticket.Item(Item) Then
                            IsInIndex = x
                        End If
                    Next

                    If IsInIndex = -1 Then
                        Dim ITEM_Count_Temp(ITEM_Count.GetLength(0), ITEM_Count.GetLength(0)) As String
                        ITEM_Count_Temp = ITEM_Count
                        ReDim ITEM_Count(ITEM_Count.GetLength(0), 1)
                        For x As Integer = 0 To ITEM_Count_Temp.GetLength(0) - 1
                            For y As Integer = 0 To ITEM_Count_Temp.GetLength(1) - 1
                                ITEM_Count(x, y) = ITEM_Count_Temp(x, y)
                            Next
                        Next


                        ITEM_Count(ITEM_Count.GetLength(0) - 1, 0) = Ticket.Item(Item)
                        ITEM_Count(ITEM_Count.GetLength(0) - 1, 1) = 1
                    Else
                        ITEM_Count(IsInIndex, 1) = ITEM_Count(IsInIndex, 1) + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                'IF NULL
            End If


            i = i + 1
        Next

        'CI_COUNT FILLING
        'ORDERING BY COUNT
        Dim ITEM_obj = New List(Of obj)
        Dim ITEM_ToObj As String = ""
        Dim ITEMCount_ToObj As String = ""

        For x As Integer = 0 To ITEM_Count.GetLength(0) - 1
            ITEM_ToObj = ITEM_Count(x, 0)
            ITEMCount_ToObj = ITEM_Count(x, 1)
            ITEM_obj.Add(New obj(ITEM_ToObj, ITEMCount_ToObj))
        Next


        ITEM_obj = OrderItem(ITEM_obj)

        Dim Item_Count_listview As ListViewItem

        For Each Itemobj As obj In ITEM_obj
            Dim Transfer_Array(2) As String
            Transfer_Array(0) = Itemobj.Item
            Transfer_Array(1) = Itemobj.Item_Count
            Item_Count_listview = New ListViewItem(Transfer_Array)
            Select Case Item
                Case "Product_Name"
                    CI_Count_Table.Items.Add(Item_Count_listview)
                Case "Status"
                    Status_Count_Table.Items.Add(Item_Count_listview)
                Case "Language"
                    Language_Count_Table.Items.Add(Item_Count_listview)
                Case "Assigned_Group"
                    AssignedGroup_Count_Table.Items.Add(Item_Count_listview)
                Case "Priority"
                    Priority_Count_Table.Items.Add(Item_Count_listview)
                Case "Company"
                    LOB_Count_Table.Items.Add(Item_Count_listview)
                Case Else
                    MsgBox("No Category Of this type exist. Programming Issue. Item is: " & Item)
            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

What is not possible to run into a background worker like this?

regards,

Comment: Read the msdn docs on how to use a backgroundWorker properly. You need to set the result in the dowork event and in the completed event you can use the result as the completed event runs on the main thread. U shouldnt interact with the UI from within the dowork event

Comment: The error is likely in your `Data.Load()` code because you are doing something to display the data on the UI thread without marshaling it. What does that code look like?

Comment: I tried to use e.result = OBDC_reader and use that after in the completed part without success. I got the same. I know that I can't interac with the interface while using the background worker. However, I can't find where and how i do that. I'll add the Completed part if that can help.

Comment: You have to get an exception somewhere. Try to attach the unhandled application exception handler